# IE 9,10 - [$injector-modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, gruntjs, minify

I'm using Angular 1.6.3 for my SPA application. I'm using Grunt for building production-ready version of site.

This is some code of my **gruntConfig**:

```
ngAnnotate: {
  dist: {
     files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd   : '.tmp/concat/scripts',
              src   : '*.js',
              dest  : '.tmp/concat/scripts'
             }]
         }
}
        ===
    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
      ]);
```

This is my **index.html** file:

```
...
<body ng-app="myApp"
      class="ng-cloak">

<ng-include src="'views/navbar.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-view></ng-view>
...

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
// file, where I declare angular.module
<script src="app.module.js"></script> 
<script src="app.config.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/main.js"></script>
```

In Google Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari works well. But when I try to load it in IE9, IE10 the next error occurs:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

Comment: It looks like you're minifying your code with `grunt-uglify`. Are you declaring your controllers to use safe dependency injection to support the AngularJS application in IE?

Comment: @BenBeck could you please explain how to declare controllers to use safe dep. injection?

Comment: Take a look at this article. It will show you to properly use dependency injection with code minification: https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Comment: My bet is 1.6 doesn't support IE9

Comment: @charlietfl app works without creating production build. After `grunt build` I got an error.

Comment: @BenBeck I have checked all my controllers, directives and services for DI. I added dependencies where needed. But in IE I still have an error.

Comment: @VadimShashkov are you properly using the `/*@ngInject*/` tags?

Comment: @BenBeck I'm using inline array annotation.

Comment: @VadimShashkov -- Have you enabled [Strict DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp#usage)?

Comment: @BenBeck yes. Still getting an error.

Comment: @BenBeck it perfectly works in IE11 or Edge, but when i open in IE9, IE10 it shows an error **$injector:modulerr**